# How to accommodate Amazon FIFO SQS in Laravel queue?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Amazon has announced their [new FIFO SQS service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-amazon-simple-queue-service-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-delivery-deduplication/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=launch_SQS_01491142&sc_publisher=tw_go&sc_content=SQS_FIFO_and_exactly_once_processing&sc_geo=global&sc_outcome=launches) and I'd like to use it in Laravel Queue to solve some concurrency issues.

I've created several new queues and changed the configurations. However, I got a `MissingParameter` error which says

```
The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.
```

So I modified the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SqsQueue.php`

```
public function pushRaw($payload, $queue = null, array $options = [])
{
    $response = $this->sqs->sendMessage(['QueueUrl' => $this->getQueue($queue), 'MessageBody' => $payload,
        'MessageGroupId' => env('APP_ENV', getenv('APP_ENV'))]);

    return $response->get('MessageId');
}

public function later($delay, $job, $data = '', $queue = null)
{
    $payload = $this->createPayload($job, $data);

    $delay = $this->getSeconds($delay);

    return $this->sqs->sendMessage([
        'QueueUrl' => $this->getQueue($queue), 'MessageBody' => $payload, 'DelaySeconds' => $delay,
        'MessageGroupId' => env('APP_ENV', getenv('APP_ENV'))
    ])->get('MessageId');
}
```

I'm using `APP_ENV` as the group ID (it's a single message queue so actually it doesn't matter a lot. I just want everything to be FIFO).

But I'm still getting the same error message. How could I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

(btw, where has the SDK defined `sendMessage`? I can find a stub for it but I didn't find the detailed implementation)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I want to point out to others who might stumble across the same issue that, although editing `SqsQueue.php` works, it will easily be reset by a `composer install` or `composer update`. An alternative is to implement a new `Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\ConnectorInterface` for SQS FIFO then add it to Laravel's queue manager.

**My approach is as follows:**

1. Create a new `SqsFifoQueue` class that extends `Illuminate\Queue\SqsQueue` but supports SQS FIFO.
2. Create a new `SqsFifoConnector` class that extends `Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\SqsConnector` that would establish a connection using `SqsFifoQueue`.
3. Create a new `SqsFifoServiceProvider` that registers the `SqsFifoConnector` to Laravel's queue manager.
4. Add `SqsFifoServiceProvider` to your `config/app.php`.
5. Update `config/queue.php` to use the new SQS FIFO Queue driver.

**Example:**

1. Create a new `SqsFifoQueue` class that extends `Illuminate\Queue\SqsQueue` but supports SQS FIFO.

   ```php
   <?php

   class SqsFifoQueue extends \Illuminate\Queue\SqsQueue
   {
       public function pushRaw($payload, $queue = null, array $options = [])
       {
           $response = $this->sqs->sendMessage([
               'QueueUrl' => $this->getQueue($queue),
               'MessageBody' => $payload,
               'MessageGroupId' => uniqid(),
               'MessageDeduplicationId' => uniqid(),
           ]);

           return $response->get('MessageId');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a new `SqsFifoConnector` class that extends `Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\SqsConnector` that would establish a connection using `SqsFifoQueue`.

   ```php
   <?php

   use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;
   use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

   class SqsFifoConnector extends \Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\SqsConnector
   {
       public function connect(array $config)
       {
           $config = $this->getDefaultConfiguration($config);

           if ($config['key'] && $config['secret']) {
               $config['credentials'] = Arr::only($config, ['key', 'secret']);
           }

           return new SqsFifoQueue(
               new SqsClient($config), $config['queue'], Arr::get($config, 'prefix', '')
           );
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a new `SqsFifoServiceProvider` that registers the `SqsFifoConnector` to Laravel's queue manager.

   ```php
   <?php

   class SqsFifoServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
   {
       public function register()
       {
           $this->app->afterResolving('queue', function ($manager) {
               $manager->addConnector('sqsfifo', function () {
                   return new SqsFifoConnector;
               });
           });
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add `SqsFifoServiceProvider` to your `config/app.php`.

   ```php
   <?php

   return [
       'providers'     => [
           ...
           SqsFifoServiceProvider::class,
       ],
   ];
   ```
5. Update `config/queue.php` to use the new SQS FIFO Queue driver.

   ```php
   <?php

   return [

       'default' => 'sqsfifo',

       'connections' => [
           'sqsfifo' => [
               'driver' => 'sqsfifo',
               'key'    => 'my_key'
               'secret' => 'my_secret',
               'queue'  => 'my_queue_url',
               'region' => 'my_sqs_region',
           ],
       ],
   ];
   ```

Then your queue should now support SQS FIFO Queues.

*Shameless plug: While working on the steps above I've created a [laravel-sqs-fifo](https://packagist.org/packages/maqe/laravel-sqs-fifo) composer package to handle this at https://github.com/maqe/laravel-sqs-fifo.*

Comment: I had to add in my prefix into the `sqsfifo` connection in `config/queue.php` but other than that, this works flawlessly!

Comment: 'MessageGroupId' => uniqid(), breaks the FIFO guarantee. Why not use a regular queue at that point? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html

Comment: @Greg, another more mature and actively maintained package for SQS FIFO queues in Laravel is [shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue). Hope that helps.

Comment: @Greg The difference that I see (unless I misunderstand the docs) is that it will still ensure messages will only be processed once in a single producer setup. For my use case, the order doesn't really matter, but standard queues don't guarantee messages won't be processed multiple times. So this approach should work for me. Hopefully I'm right!

Answer (score 3):

FIFO message works in a different way than standard AWS SQS queues.

You need a separate driver for handling FIFO queues.

I had to face the same situation and the below package was a lifesaver.

https://packagist.org/packages/shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue

in `queue.php`

```
'sqs-fifo' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs-fifo',
            'key' => env('SQS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('SQS_SECRET'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE'),
            'region' => env('SQS_REGION'),
            'group' => 'default',
            'deduplicator' => 'unique',
        ],
```

then

```
dispatch(new TestJob([]))->onQueue('My_Mail_Queue.fifo');
```

NB:
you need to specify default queue name you are going to use in your application in the `.env`

```
SQS_QUEUE=My_Default_queue.fifo
```

Also, you need to specify all the queue names you are going to use in your application in the listener. (if you are using the same queue name for the whole application, you don't need to specify the queue name in the listener)

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=My_Default_queue.fifo,My_Mail_Queue.fifo,My_Message_Queue.fifo
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `MessageGroupId`, it needs a `MessageDeduplicationId` or enabling content-based deduplication.